# How to put 'Bullets' to right side of text.

Tags: windows, right-to-left

Trying to have dual language English and Arabic text.
Want to have one text box with conventional English format (bullets to left)
Want to have second text box with Arabic (bullets to right)

Answer (score 1):

Please press right Ctrl and Shift button Simultaneously and also change the language to Arabic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in HTML, you can use document direction attribute (`dir`)= 'ltr'.

Pack your Arabic list in a div and set its attribute: `dir="ltr"`